# How to link to .dlls in conda environment using a Python Script running a Windows .exe?

Tags: python, windows, qt, subprocess

I am using a script populating the Structure-from-Motion software COLMAP with custom features.
This script is usually distributed for linux and I had to do some adaptions in Windows 10.

The script is calling COLMAP via:

```
cmd = [
        str(colmap_path), 'feature_importer',
        '--database_path', str(database_path),
        '--image_path', str(image_dir),
        '--import_path', str(dummy_dir),
        '--ImageReader.single_camera',
        str(int(single_camera))]
    ret = subprocess.call(cmd)
    if ret != 0:
        logging.warning('Problem with feature_importer, exiting.')
        exit(ret)
```

For `colmap_path` I linked to the colmap.exe and it gets executed but is missing the .dlls that are stored in a separate folder. The structure of the program is as follows:

- C:/COLMAP/bin/colmap.exe (and other *.exe)
- C:/COLMAP/lib/*.dll
- C:/COLMAP/lib/platforms/qwindows.dll

My attempt was to just copy the .dll files into /anaconda3/envs/my_env but then I am getting the error:

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could
> be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

So is it possible to directly link to the .dlls and platforms in `ret = subprocess.call(cmd)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on a different [website](https://derpfaff.de/2016/03/qt-fehler-beim-laden-des-platform-plugins-windows/). I had to copy the platforms folder containing the qwindows.dll into the bin folder. This works as a solution for many different applications executable with a .exe; `subprocess.call` was then able to find the qt platform plugin and the script ran without errors.